# How to increase performance of a pybind11 iterator

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a C++ container of `Thing` objects of another library which I need to iterate very fast in Python. Each `Thing` object has a number of attributes which I can access through its getters.

Most of my approaches are working fine, but they are all too slow. Except 1. I use a custom iterator in C++ which I've wrapped by passing it to `pybind11::make_iterator`. Here's what I have come up with so far:

1. Using the original iterator of the container --> very slow as I cross the C++|Python border for each Thing object on each call to one of its getters.
2. A custom C++ iterator retrieving relevant attributes from `Thing` and store them in a `pybind11::tuple` --> 5-10 times faster but still too slow for my puposes.

   ```
    pybind11::tuple operator*() {
        Thing const& thing = *m_it;

        m_current = pybind11::make_tuple(thing.GetParam1(), thing.GetParam2());
        return m_current;
    }
   ```
3. A custom C++ iterator storing the information in chunks of `pybind11::tuple` to reduce the crossing of the Python|C++ border --> performance is similar to 2.
4. A custom iterator, that runs a thread to do the conversion and buffering the results. This only works if I do not use any Python objects inside the thread function. I assume this has something to do with the GIL. If I use `std::vector` or `std::tuple` here, pybind11 automatically converts them to some Python class, i.e. `std::tuple<double, double>` becomes something like `DoubleTuple` in Python. The conversion costs too much performance, I guess.

My question is, if it is possible to use the 4. option in combination with Python objects. I have tried a bit with releasing and acquiring the GIL, but with no success. My program gets stuck if I try to create any Python object. Even if this works, I doubt it will be much faster as of my understanding acquiring the GIL pauses the main Python thread.

Maybe somebody could think of any alternative route I could go. I have to use pybind11 though.